# does Visual Studio 2015 include .edmx support?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2015, edmx, edmx-designer

Does Visual Studio 2015 include .edmx support?

I have a project that includes an .edmx data model and double-clicking it in VS2015 just opens the XML editor.

There's no DbContext generator option in the file->new dialog.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During setup of VS2015, go to the advanced options and select Web or Database Development tools. Now the Installers install the EF tools (Designer + templates). If you have VS already installed, to the Programs & features in control panel and modify the currently installed VS2015.

Comment: Hi, i reinstalled VS2015 update 3 with "Database Development Tools" included, still cannot fix this problem. The project itself was from vs2013 and converted to 2015. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @user3552178 try to select web development tools in setup

Comment: This is what i did, did default vs2015 install which has web develop tools. Convert 2013 project into 2015, found issue.    uninstall 2015, reinstall with both database develop tool and web develop tool, still no good.

Comment: If you are using VS2017, the fix is slightly different: "Visual Studio Installer" shortcut under Start menu>All Programs (Programs and Features won't help), and then under 'Individual Components' in the installer, scroll to the SDKs & libraries section, and select "Entity Framework 6 tools".

Comment: @scradam this question is about 2015. Ask your own question about VS2017 and add your own answer.

Answer (score 11):

You have to select the **Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools** in the VS2015 setup to get this editor back.

NOTE: You can modify the current installation via Program And Features as magicandre1981 has already suggested.

[see how this is done here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHEH3.jpg)