# " ADO.net Entity data model " option in visual studio 2015 is missing?

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

After I Install this setup file in here http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki which is an ADO.net provider for SQLite with exactly following the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39322959/9131071
with
**Install the designer components for Visual Studio 2015** option being checked.

When I reinstall the same without the above option being checked - I could see the option listed there.

Now, what is the solution to get this.. since I need both an ADO.net provider and the option on the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [does Visual Studio 2015 include .edmx support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212919/does-visual-studio-2015-include-edmx-support)

Comment: No, it is not - This ADO.net provider is very random.. i guess someone who actually knows it well should clear the things here